# Xcode will no longer open project

Tags: xcode

Xcode won't open a project workspace. It immediately quits and throws this error report. Everything was fine on my last commit. I'm not sure how go about finding the issue. It says `Assertion failed: _numberOfTabsForLayout > 1` I don't have any type of tab bar in this project but I did close the project with multiple tabs open in the workspace.

```
Process:               Xcode [8382]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.4 (7720)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7720000000000000~8
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812725084
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [8382]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-18 20:06:46.433 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        2C67D893-30CC-08A5-E12A-E03DD1BAEFBD

Sleep/Wake UUID:       844DC3EB-F2C2-496A-BEEB-C72AE1AFE3F9

Time Awake Since Boot: 48000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6E35b
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-7714/DVTKit/Tabs/DVTScrollableTabBarView.m:1270
Details:  Assertion failed: _numberOfTabsForLayout > 1
Object:   <DVTScrollableTabBarView: 0x7fd3dfa81230>
Method:   -_calculateStackingRegions
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd3da5207f0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000103b8cfda -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
```

**Update**: I figured out how to get it to open but not how to resolve the problem. If I disconnect my second monitor it will open and work just fine. I can reconnect the monitor once it's open and everything is fine. But each time I need to reopen the project I have to pull the HDMI cable out.

Comment: Why not diff vs. the last commit and see if you can find the difference?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same crash with exactly the same `DVTScrollableTabBarView.m:1270` assertion failure. Did you find out anything?

Comment: Unplugging HDMI worked for me too!

Comment: @epologee If you disconnect any HDMI outputs the project will open. I have not figured out how to resolve the issue though. Every time I open the project I disconnect my monitor.